# Batch File: Multiple Commands on one line with Set

Tags: batch-file

I have a framework where I can only run stuff through PowerShell, but I need to run batch file commands.  I'm trying to run a PowerShell Script, something like:

```
cmd /c blah
```

for `blah` I want to do something like:

```
set myPath = c:\theDir && if not exist %myPath% mkdir %myPath%
```

This will not work the first time I run it as the `set` command doesn't seem to take affect until the second line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is because `cmd` evaluates variables when a line is *parsed*, not when it's *run*. To get the latter behaviour you'll have to use delayed expansion:

```
cmd /c /v:on "set MyPath=C:\theDir&& if not exist "!myPath!" mkdir "!myPath!"
```

Note also that you must not have spaces around the `=` in a `set`, otherwise you're creating a variable name with a space at the end (which is to say, your approach would never have worked anyway).

Comment: In accordance with the question, I think you meant to concatenate those two lines in your answer into one line using the '&' , didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
for %d in (some\path and\maybe\another\one) do @if not exist "%d" md "%d"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define the delayed expansion before you run multiple commands. That way you would not have to open a new CMD instance:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set say=Hello && echo !say! && echo Done!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this

```
SET _KillElevated=1& SET _KillWithGrace=1
```